# Limiting Component Size in JText Area in Vertical JScrollPane within Horizontal JScrollPane

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jtextarea, gridbaglayout, boxlayout

*How do I limit the vertical size of components within a horizontal scroll pane to the vertical size of the scroll pane?*

The GUI should always look something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlxBZ.png]

Here's what I get after I scroll the horizontal scroll bar:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1LLE.png]

Relevant code snippets: creating the frame, adding sensor columns.  Also tried this earlier with BoxLayout, same issue.

```
frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 764, 494);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{500, 500};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] {439,45};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 0.0};
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("CSV Builder -- Development Version StackOverflow Example");

    //Panel for holding the text areas for each sensor
    JPanel sensorPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout sensorGridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    sensorGridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] {40,40,39};
    sensorGridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0,1.0, 0.0};
    sensorPanel.setLayout(sensorGridBagLayout);

    //Scroll pane on horizontal box
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(sensorPanel);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 0;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 0;
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

    //Set up text areas for each sensor
    for(int k = 0; k < EngineDataParser.titles.length; k++){    

        //Make Label
        JLabel lblEngineTemperature = new JLabel(EngineDataParser.titles[k]);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblEngineTemperature = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblEngineTemperature.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblEngineTemperature.gridx = k;
        gbc_lblEngineTemperature.gridy = 1;
        gbc_lblEngineTemperature.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

        //Make text area
        JTextArea sensorTextArea = new JTextArea();
        sensorTextArea.setLineWrap(false);
        sensorTextArea.setText("No Data Yet");
        sensorTextArea.setBounds(50,50,50,200);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_sensorTextArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_sensorTextArea.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);

        //Add scroll pane
        JScrollPane sensorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(sensorTextArea);
        sensorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        sensorScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        sensorScrollPane.setBounds(50,50,50,200);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_sensorScrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_sensorScrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_sensorScrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridx = k;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 2;
        gbc_scrollPane.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc_scrollPane.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc_scrollPane.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        //make checkbox
        JCheckBox exportCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Export "+EngineDataParser.titles[k]);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_exportCheckBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        exportCheckBox.addActionListener(checkboxListener);
        gbc_exportCheckBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_exportCheckBox.gridx = k;
        gbc_exportCheckBox.gridy = 3;
        gbc_exportCheckBox.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;

        //add all to panel
        sensorPanel.add(lblEngineTemperature, gbc_lblEngineTemperature);
        sensorPanel.add(sensorScrollPane, gbc_sensorScrollPane);
        sensorPanel.add(exportCheckBox, gbc_exportCheckBox);

        //add all to arrays for later adjusting
        sensorLabels.add(lblEngineTemperature);
        sensorTextAreas.add(sensorTextArea);
        sensorCheckBoxes.add(exportCheckBox);

    }
```

**********That's the main idea, copious details and runnable code follows in case it helps**********

Background: I'm making a GUI for an engine test system.  I have a JPanel with GridBagLayout inside a JScrollPane with a horizontal scroll bar.  In each column of the panel, there is a title, text area with scroll pane containing a column of sensor data, and a check box asking the user if they want to export that column of data.

Intent:  When the user loads a file, it will read data from an engine log, separate out each sensor to a separate column in the JPanel, and export any checked columns when the export button is pressed.

What's Working: All the back end file handling/separation works.

Problem:  After a file loads and the horizontal scrollbar is moved, the text areas become vertically large and extend below the horizontal JScrollPane.

I've tried both using a GridBagLayout and BoxLayout to solve this problem.  Box layout looks correct at first, but shows the same noxious behaviour on horizontal scrolling.

GridBagLayout also always tries to add the JTextArea to the top row.  Not sure why.

I considered using a setMaximumSize() on the JTextAreas, but that might make them too small if the user resizes the whole window (which is the whole reason I'm bothering with layout managers anyway.  Otherwise, for this small of a program I would have just used an absolute layout)

Full Code, main GUI:
    Here's the code:

```
package engineSensorReader;

import java.awt.Color;


public class CSVBuilder {

/*Creates a GUI that builds a CSV file from an file of raw serial output from a sensor array
 * Each line of the unprocessed file looks like so
 * <TEMP1:123,TEMP2:122,TEMP3:124,GLAT:1138, ... PONT:1,>
 * Each file has a different set of sensors
 * The program puts each sensor in a separate column with a check box beneath it
 * If the user leaves the box checked, that column is written to a CSV file the user exports
 */

//Globally accessible GUI components 
private JFrame frame;
JTextArea engineTemperatureTextArea = new JTextArea();
JButton loadFileButton = new JButton("Load File");
JFileChooser fileFinder = new JFileChooser();
JButton exportFileButton = new JButton("Export File");

//Lists of components pertaining to each sensor
private List<JLabel> sensorLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
private List<JTextArea> sensorTextAreas = new ArrayList<JTextArea>();
private List<JCheckBox> sensorCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();

//Text are for raw file 
private JTextArea rawFileTextArea = new JTextArea();
private JScrollPane rawFileScrollPane = new JScrollPane(); 

//instantiate custom data parser object
EngineDataParser dataParser = new EngineDataParser();

//array of booleans tells us if we want a certain sensor in the output file
private boolean[] exportSensorChecks = new boolean[EngineDataParser.titles.length];

private boolean fileIsImported = false;

private Color greenish = new Color(196,250,185);
private Color reddish = new Color(250,199,185);


public static void main(String[] args){
    CSVBuilder mCSVBuilder = new CSVBuilder();
}

public JFrame getFrame() {
    return frame;
}

public CSVBuilder() {
    initialize();
}

void initialize() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 764, 494);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{500, 500};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] {439,45};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 0.0};
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Image mainIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/hat.png")).getImage();
    frame.setIconImage(mainIcon);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("CSV Builder -- Development Version StackOverflow Example");

    //Panel for holding the text areas for each sensor
    JPanel sensorPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout sensorGridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    sensorGridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] {40,40,39};
    sensorGridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0,1.0, 0.0};
    sensorPanel.setLayout(sensorGridBagLayout);

    //Scroll pane on horizontal box
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(sensorPanel);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 0;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 0;
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

    //Set up text areas for each sensor
    for(int k = 0; k < EngineDataParser.titles.length; k++){    

        //Make Label
        JLabel lblEngineTemperature = new JLabel(EngineDataParser.titles[k]);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblEngineTemperature = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblEngineTemperature.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblEngineTemperature.gridx = k;
        gbc_lblEngineTemperature.gridy = 1;
        gbc_lblEngineTemperature.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

        //Make text area
        JTextArea sensorTextArea = new JTextArea();
        sensorTextArea.setLineWrap(false);
        sensorTextArea.setText("No Data Yet");
        sensorTextArea.setBounds(50,50,50,200);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_sensorTextArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_sensorTextArea.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);

        //Add scroll pane
        JScrollPane sensorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(sensorTextArea);
        sensorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        sensorScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        sensorScrollPane.setBounds(50,50,50,200);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_sensorScrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_sensorScrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_sensorScrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridx = k;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 2;
        gbc_scrollPane.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc_scrollPane.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc_scrollPane.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        //make checkbox
        JCheckBox exportCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Export "+EngineDataParser.titles[k]);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_exportCheckBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        exportCheckBox.addActionListener(checkboxListener);
        gbc_exportCheckBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_exportCheckBox.gridx = k;
        gbc_exportCheckBox.gridy = 3;
        gbc_exportCheckBox.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;

        //add all to panel
        sensorPanel.add(lblEngineTemperature, gbc_lblEngineTemperature);
        sensorPanel.add(sensorScrollPane, gbc_sensorScrollPane);
        sensorPanel.add(exportCheckBox, gbc_exportCheckBox);

        //add all to arrays for later adjusting
        sensorLabels.add(lblEngineTemperature);
        sensorTextAreas.add(sensorTextArea);
        sensorCheckBoxes.add(exportCheckBox);

    }       

    Box buttonBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_buttonBox = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_buttonBox.gridx = 1;
    gbc_buttonBox.gridy = 1;
    gbc_buttonBox.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    frame.getContentPane().add(buttonBox, gbc_buttonBox);

    rawFileTextArea = new JTextArea();
    rawFileTextArea.setText("No file selected yet");
    rawFileTextArea.setBounds(50,50,300,400);

    rawFileScrollPane = new JScrollPane(rawFileTextArea);
    rawFileScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    rawFileScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    JLabel rawFileLabel = new JLabel("Raw File Contents");

    Box rawFileBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    rawFileBox.add(rawFileLabel);
    rawFileBox.add(rawFileScrollPane);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_rawFileBox = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_rawFileBox.gridx = 1;
    gbc_rawFileBox.gridy = 0;
    gbc_rawFileBox.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_rawFileBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_rawFileBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    frame.getContentPane().add(rawFileBox, gbc_rawFileBox);

    loadFileButton.addActionListener(manipulateFileListener);
    buttonBox.add(loadFileButton);

    exportFileButton.addActionListener(manipulateFileListener);
    buttonBox.add(exportFileButton);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

//Reads raw serial file to text areas
private void readFileToBoxes(File importedFile) throws IOException{
    try{
        FileReader importReader = new FileReader(importedFile); 
        BufferedReader readFileReader = new BufferedReader(importReader);
        StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int)importedFile.length());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(importedFile);
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String currentSensorReading;
        String readLineString;

        try {
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                readLineString = scanner.nextLine();
                rawFileTextArea.append(readLineString +"\n");
                dataParser.interpret(readLineString);
                if(dataParser.readyToOutput){
                    int newNumber = 0;
                    for(int h = 0; h<EngineDataParser.titles.length;h++){
                        if(fileIsImported == false){ //Check if this is first run through
                            sensorTextAreas.get(h).setText("");
                        }
                        currentSensorReading = EngineDataParser.getLastNumericalReadings()[h];
                        if(currentSensorReading!=null){
                            sensorTextAreas.get(h).append(currentSensorReading+"\n");
                            sensorTextAreas.get(h).setBackground(greenish);
                            sensorCheckBoxes.get(h).setSelected(true);
                            exportSensorChecks[h] = true;
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("no data," + EngineDataParser.titles[h] + "iterator: "+ h);
                            sensorTextAreas.get(h).append(currentSensorReading+"\n");
                            sensorTextAreas.get(h).setBackground(reddish);
                            sensorCheckBoxes.get(h).setSelected(false);
                            exportSensorChecks[h] = false;
                        }

                    }
                    fileIsImported = true;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException didNotFindFile){
        didNotFindFile.printStackTrace();
        engineTemperatureTextArea.setText("File chosen but not found"); 
    }
}

//Writes appropriate columns to CSV file
private void saveFileToCSV(File fileToSave){
    String dataLine = "";
    try {
        PrintWriter writeToCSVWriter = new PrintWriter(fileToSave);
        for(int sensor = 0; sensor <EngineDataParser.titles.length; sensor++){
            if(exportSensorChecks[sensor] == true){
                writeToCSVWriter.print(EngineDataParser.titles[sensor]);
                writeToCSVWriter.print(",");
            }
        }

        for(int dataPoint = 0; dataPoint <= dataParser.getWriteToIndex(); dataPoint++){
            dataLine = "";
            for(int sensor = 0; sensor <EngineDataParser.titles.length; sensor++){
                if(exportSensorChecks[sensor] == true){
                    System.out.println("To here, printing data point");
                    dataLine  += dataParser.getAssignedDataPoint(sensor, dataPoint) + ",";
                }
            }
            writeToCSVWriter.println(dataLine);
        }
        writeToCSVWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Check box listener handles...well, checkboxes and coloring text areas
ActionListener checkboxListener = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent boxChecked){
        for(int boxIndex = 0; boxIndex < EngineDataParser.titles.length; boxIndex ++){
            if(boxChecked.getSource() == sensorCheckBoxes.get(boxIndex)){
                if(sensorCheckBoxes.get(boxIndex).isSelected()){
                    exportSensorChecks[boxIndex] = true;
                    sensorTextAreas.get(boxIndex).setBackground(greenish);
                }else{
                    exportSensorChecks[boxIndex] = false;
                    sensorTextAreas.get(boxIndex).setBackground(reddish);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

//Action listener handles file importing and exporting
ActionListener manipulateFileListener = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == loadFileButton){
            int whatHappens = fileFinder.showOpenDialog(frame);
            if(whatHappens == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                File importedFile = fileFinder.getSelectedFile();
                try{
                    readFileToBoxes(importedFile);
                }catch(IOException didNotFindFile){
                    didNotFindFile.printStackTrace();
                    engineTemperatureTextArea.setText("File chosen but something else failed"); 
                }
                engineTemperatureTextArea.setText("We chose the file: " + importedFile.getName());
            }else{
                engineTemperatureTextArea.setText("We somehow failed to choose a file");
            }
        }else if(e.getSource() == exportFileButton){
            int whatHappens = fileFinder.showSaveDialog(frame);
            if(whatHappens == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                File exportFile = fileFinder.getSelectedFile();
                saveFileToCSV(exportFile);
                engineTemperatureTextArea.setText("We exported the file: " + exportFile.getName());

                if(exportFile.getName().indexOf(".csv") < 0 && exportFile.getName().indexOf(".txt") < 0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Unrecognized file extension or no extension used.  Consider re-saving as .txt (for using CSV builder) or .csv (for easier use with spreadsheet)");
                }

            }else{
                engineTemperatureTextArea.setText("We somehow failed to choose a file");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Data Parsing Class

```
package engineSensorReader;

import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class EngineDataParser implements Runnable {

static boolean readyToOutput = false; //shows we have data ready to update a GUI or whatever
static boolean enableFileWrite = false; //will be set to true if we want to log this data to a file
static boolean listsOfPointsCreated = false; //tells us we need to make titles and all

//Arraylists for each sensor reading.  We won't always have all of them but that's alright
ArrayList<String> engineTemperatures = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> transmissionTemperatures = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> ambientTemperatures = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> auxiliaryTemperatures = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> engineRPMs = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> cVTDrivenRPMs = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> gPSLatitudes = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> gPSLongitudes = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> gPSAltitudes = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> gPSFixes = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> fuelLevels = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> throttlePositions = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> pointCounts = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> auxiliarySensor1Readings = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> auxiliarySensor2Readings = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> auxiliarySensor3Readings = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allDataArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

private int writeToIndex = 0;

//String ArrayList of titles for each
static String[] titles = {"Transmission Temperature","Engine Temperature","Ambient Temperature","Auxiliary Temperature","Engine RPM","CVT Driven RPM","GPS Latitidue (Decimal Degrees)","GPS Longitude (Decimal Degrees)","GPS Altitude","GPS Fix (1 or 0)","Fuel Level","Throttle Position","Point Count","Auxilary Sensor 1","Auxilary Sensor 2","Auxilary Sensor 3"};

private static volatile String[] lastNumericalReadings = new String[titles.length];

public void run(){

}

public String getAssignedDataPoint(int sensorIndex, int readingNumber){
    String foundValue = "";
    if(sensorIndex < titles.length){
        if(sensorIndex == 0){
            if(readingNumber < transmissionTemperatures.size()){
                foundValue = transmissionTemperatures.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 1){
            if(readingNumber < engineTemperatures.size()){
                foundValue = engineTemperatures.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 2){
            if(readingNumber <ambientTemperatures.size()){
                foundValue = ambientTemperatures.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 3){
            if(readingNumber <auxiliaryTemperatures.size()){
                foundValue = auxiliaryTemperatures.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 4){
            if(readingNumber <engineRPMs.size()){
                foundValue = engineRPMs.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 5){
            if(readingNumber <cVTDrivenRPMs.size()){
                foundValue = cVTDrivenRPMs.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 6){
            if(readingNumber <gPSLatitudes.size()){
                foundValue = gPSLatitudes.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 7){
            if(readingNumber <gPSLongitudes.size()){
                foundValue = gPSLongitudes.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 8){
            if(readingNumber <gPSAltitudes.size()){
                foundValue = gPSAltitudes.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 8){
            if(readingNumber <gPSFixes.size()){
                foundValue = gPSFixes.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 10){
            if(readingNumber <fuelLevels.size()){
                foundValue = fuelLevels.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 11){
            if(readingNumber <throttlePositions.size()){
                foundValue = throttlePositions.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 12){
            if(readingNumber <pointCounts.size()){
                foundValue = pointCounts.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 13){
            if(readingNumber <auxiliarySensor1Readings.size()){
                foundValue = auxiliarySensor1Readings.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 14){
            if(readingNumber <auxiliarySensor2Readings.size()){
                foundValue = auxiliarySensor2Readings.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }else if(sensorIndex == 15){
            if(readingNumber <auxiliarySensor3Readings.size()){
                foundValue = auxiliarySensor3Readings.get(readingNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    if(foundValue.equals("")){
        foundValue = "0";
        System.out.println("HULLO? No sensor at requested index");
        System.out.print(" (Index: " + sensorIndex + "readingNumber: " + readingNumber +")");
        System.out.println(readingNumber);  
    }
    return foundValue;

}

public int countAvailableSensors(String stringIn){
    String[] bitsOfData = stringIn.split(",");
    System.out.print("The bits of data: ");
    System.out.println(bitsOfData);
    System.out.print("There are "+bitsOfData.length+" sensors.");
    return bitsOfData.length;

}

public void interpret(String stringIn){
    //take last data point from SerialReader
    //      System.out.println("Parser Called");
    //split at commas
    String[] bitsOfData = stringIn.split(",");

    //Check that we have a full string
    if(stringIn.indexOf("<") != -1 && stringIn.indexOf(">") != -1){
        //go through token by token
        for(String token : bitsOfData){
            //System.out.println(token);
            if(token.indexOf("TMP") != -1){//We have found a temperature reading
                //Split at :
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                //Find title (T1, T2 etc)

                //Add to appropriate list of sensorReadings
                if(tokenSplit[0].indexOf("1")!=-1){
                    //We have transmission temperatures
                    transmissionTemperatures.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                    lastNumericalReadings[0] = tokenSplit[1];
                }else if(tokenSplit[0].indexOf("2")!=-1){
                    //we have engine temperature
                    engineTemperatures.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                    lastNumericalReadings[1]= tokenSplit[1];
                }else if(tokenSplit[0].indexOf("3")!=-1){
                    //we have ambient temperature
                    ambientTemperatures.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                    lastNumericalReadings[2]= tokenSplit[1];
                }else if(tokenSplit[0].indexOf("4")!=-1){
                    //we have aux temperature
                    auxiliaryTemperatures.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                    lastNumericalReadings[3]= tokenSplit[1];
                }
            }else if(token.indexOf("RPM1") != -1){//We have found engine RPM reading
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                engineRPMs.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[4]= tokenSplit[1];
            }else if(token.indexOf("RPM2")!=-1){//We have found CVT Driven RPM
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                lastNumericalReadings[5]= tokenSplit[1];
                cVTDrivenRPMs.add(tokenSplit[1]);
            }else if(token.indexOf("GLON") != -1){//We have found GPS Latitude
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                gPSLatitudes.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[6]= tokenSplit[1];
            }else if(token.indexOf("GLAT") != -1){//We have found GPS Longitude
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                gPSLongitudes.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[7]= tokenSplit[1];
            }else if(token.indexOf("GALT") != -1){//We have found GPS Altitude
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                gPSAltitudes.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[8]= tokenSplit[1];
            }else if(token.indexOf("GFIX") != -1){//We have found GPS Fix
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                gPSFixes.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[9]= tokenSplit[1];
            }else if(token.indexOf("FUL1") != -1){//We have found fuel level
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                fuelLevels.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[10]= tokenSplit[1];
            }else if(token.indexOf("TPS1") != -1){//We have found throttle position
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                throttlePositions.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[11]= tokenSplit[1];
            }else if(token.indexOf("PNT1")!= -1){//We have found point count
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                pointCounts.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[12]= tokenSplit[1];
            }else if(token.indexOf("AUX1")!= -1){//We have found Auxilary Sensor 1
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                auxiliarySensor1Readings.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[13]= tokenSplit[1];
            }else if(token.indexOf("AUX2")!= -1){//We have found Auxilary Sensor 2
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                auxiliarySensor2Readings.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[14]= tokenSplit[1];
            }else if(token.indexOf("AUX3")!= -1){//We have found Auxilary Sensor 3
                String[] tokenSplit = token.split(":");
                auxiliarySensor3Readings.add(tokenSplit[1]);
                lastNumericalReadings[15]= tokenSplit[1];
            }
        }

        setWriteToIndex(getWriteToIndex() + 1);
        //if this is the first time through, say we're now ready for output and reset WriteToIndex
        if(readyToOutput == false){
            readyToOutput = true;
            setWriteToIndex(0);

            //              for(String reading:lastNumericalReadings){
            //              
            //              }
        }
        System.out.println("Here's the last numerical readings: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(lastNumericalReadings));

    }else{
        System.out.println("We didn't get a full string");
    }

}


public static String[] getLastNumericalReadings(){
    return lastNumericalReadings;
}

public int getWriteToIndex() {
    return writeToIndex;
}

public void setWriteToIndex(int writeToIndex) {
    this.writeToIndex = writeToIndex;
}
}
```

A line from an imported file looks like this. Unfortunately they look like HTML tags so posting the whole file is problematic.  But typical imported files are just a bunch of lines similar to this, so if you're adventurous enough to test this just paste it in a .txt a million times.

```
                  <TMP1:142,TMP2:144,TMP3:138,RPM1:3708,RPM2:1280,GLAT:4042.6142,GLON:07400.4168,GALT:545.4,GFIX:0,FUL1:110.00,TPS1:210,TPS1:336,PNT1:0,>,
```

Answer (score 0):

Way too much code to look at to see what you are doing. When you ask a question you should post simple code that demonstrates the problem. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for more information.

> How do I limit the vertical size of components within a horizontal scroll pane to the vertical size of the scroll pane?

The panel you add to the scroll pane needs to implement the `Scrollable` interface. In particular you need the `getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()` method to return `true`.

To save you implement the entire interface yourself you may want to check out the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/). This class implements the methods for you and you can just set properties on the class to achieve your desired result. It sound to me like your would need to use the `FIT` property for the scrollable height.